# Use ES6 'import' statement without transpilers

Tags: node.js, module, ecmascript-6, transpiler

I have nodejs v8

```
$ node -v
v8.1.3
```

and a script:

```
import cmd from "commander";
```

There is an error "*Unexpected token import*" when I try to launch this script:

```
$ node script.js
/.../script.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import cmd from "commander";
                                                              ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Does any method exist to use ES6 modules ("import" statement) without transpiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using transpiler, you have to use `require`:

```
const cmd = require('commander');
```

Comment: This is not correct, require is not an equivalent. You can use `import xxx from 'yyy'` now. Files have to be .mjs and for now the `--experimental-modules` flag has to be supplied.

Use @std/esm if you wish to pack or bundle files or use babel. Which to be quite frank is an asinine situation to be in. As all the bundlers such as Webpack were developed for the client side. Server side is an after thought

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is no longer the correct answer. In NodeJS 4+, you can now enable ES modules by installing the `@std/esm` package and calling your script with the `-r @std/esm` option on the command line. For example:

`node -r @std/esm index.js`

Note that in order to have Node auto-detect if a file should use ESM (to allow you to use `.js` file extensions instead of using the Michael Jackson solution, `.mjs`), you'll have to add to your `package.json` the following:

`"@std/esm": {
    "esm": "js"
  },`

See full details at [standard-things/esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) on GitHub.